# Переставить слои местами

Tags: c++

Какие возможности есть по следующему заданию???

```
// массивы. Проинициализируйте трехмерный массив
//double dArray[4][3][3] так, как показано на рисунке и напишите фрагмент
//кода, который меняет местами значения элементов четных
//и нечетных слоев:
//  было:                |--------|     
//                     / |4  4  4 |     
//                   |--------| 4 | 
//                 / |3  3  3 | 4 | 
//               |---------|3 |   |
//             / | 2  2  2 |3 | /
//            |---------|2 |__|
//            | 1  1  1 |2 | /
//            | 1  1  1 |__| 
//            | 1  1  1 | /
//            |_________|

//  стало:               |--------|     
//                     / |3  3  3 |     
//                   |--------| 3 | 
//                 / |4  4  4 | 3 | 
//               |---------|4 |   |
//             / | 1  1  1 |4 | /
//            |---------|1 |__|
//            | 2  2  2 |1 | /
//            | 2  2  2 |__| 
//            | 2  2  2 | /
//            |_________|

for(int i=0; i<...; ...)
{
//Замечание: НЕ НУЖНО МОДИФИЦИРОВАТЬ ВЫРАЖЕНИЯ СПРАВА ОТ ЗНАКА РАВЕНСТВА!!!
    ... =  dArray[i];
    ... =  dArray[i+1];
    //переставляем местами элементы i-того и i+1-ого слоев


}
```

Comment: Так `напишите фрагмент кода` или `заполните недостающие фрагменты кода`? Сомневаюсь, что второе можно решить.

Comment: @vp_arth  а почему нельзя? никто не запрещает написать ещё 1 строку ниже.

Comment: Просто там нет многоточия)  Однако, эту строчку можно впарить в инкремент цикла)

Comment: а если с добавлением недостающего кода, то как?

Answer (score 1):

Если "с добавлением недостающего кода", то, например, так

```
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < 4; i += 2)
{
   auto &even_layer = dArray[i];
   auto &odd_layer = dArray[i+1];
   std::swap(even_layer, odd_layer);
 }
```

или, чтобы абстрагироваться от константы 4

```
for  (int i = 0; i + 1 < std::extent<decltype(dArray)>::value; i += 2)
  ...
```

Разумеется, если задаться целью вписывать код только в многоточия, то можно "скрипя сердцем" изрыгнуть что-то вроде

```
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < std::extent<decltype(dArray)>::value; i += 2)
{
  auto dummy = dArray[i];
  (std::swap(dArray[i], dArray[i + 1]), dummy) = dArray[i + 1];
}
```

Но я сомневаюсь, что в этом есть смысл.

Comment: благодарю!! чтото я затормозил!